# Understanding Histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I got the following results after applying:`[h,bins]=hist(data)`, such that, the `data` will contain the `LBP (Local Binary Pattern)` values.

> h =
>
> 221    20     6     4     1     1     2     0     0     1
>
> bins =
>
> Columns 1 through 7
>
> ```
> 8.2500   24.7500   41.2500   57.7500   74.2500   90.7500  107.2500
> ```
>
> Columns 8 through 10
>
> 123.7500  140.2500  156.7500

I want to ask the following:

- Does the first `bin` represent the values `0-8.25` and the second `bin` the values `8.26-24.75`, and so forth?
- For the `h` value `221`, does it mean that we have computed `221` an `LBP` value ranging from `0-8.25`?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html

Answer (score 1):

1) No. The bin location is in the center value of the bin, that is, for the first bin the values are `0-16.5`, the second bin is `16.5-33`, etc.  Use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) if it is more natural to specify bin edges instead of centers.

2)  `h(1)=221` means that from your entire `data` set (that has 256 elements according to your question), 221 elements had values ranging between  `0-16.5` .